# Turning FindInstance into True or False

Tags: findinstance

I have a function where I input a certain vector of parameters and it gives me the output of 16 FindInstances. So, a typical output will look something like this

```
{{{p -> 1/2, r -> 0, q -> 0}}, {}, {}, {{p -> 4/5, r -> 1/5, q -> 0}}, {}, {{p -> 10/27, r -> 2/9, q -> 11/27}}, ...}
```

(I'm stopping the output short, as you don't really need to see the entire vector.). What I am really interested in, however, is whether FindInstnace does find an instance or not.  So I would much prefer an output that has

```
{True, False, False, True, False, True, ...}
```

Looking at the documentation of FindInstance, I thought the way to get (something close to that) would involve placing "Booleans" at the end of my FindInstance.  But when I do so, I get the following error: The system is not Boolean valued at p->True,r->True,q->True.

I haven't included my actual FindInstances here since they are long and involve a series of many functions.  However, it is just a system of linear inequalities and I have no trouble getting an actual answer with FindInstance when I drop Booleans.

Any clue on something that might work?

Comment: Can you adapt this? `Map[(#!={})&,{{{p->1/2,r->0,q->0}}, {}, {}, {{p->4/5,r->1/5,q->0}}, {}, {{p->10/27,r->2/9,q->11/27}}}]` which instantly returns `{True,False,False,True,False,True}`

Comment: `FindInstance[...]=!={}`?

Comment: I am generating many of these expressions (think hundreds), so while Bill's solution technically works it would be a pain to input the output of every single function.  I don't understand AccidentalFourierTransform's respond.

Comment: I see how I can use Bill's answer: I can create a new function that puts Map[(# != {}) &, OLD FUNCTION HERE].

Comment: I had hoped that hint would be just enough to get you to think about just the right thing. And it worked! AccidentalFourierTransform's hint would work IF you ONLY wanted to know if there were zero solutions or more than zero solutions from each `FindInstance`